# efetch multiple records at once

Tags: edirect

If I want to efetch two records, I can do the following:

```
efetch -db nuccore -id AB610939,AB610940 -format fasta
```

I have hundreds of records to fetch. Can I put all the IDs in a file and efetch. If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `efetch` can be given a file with IDs. See `efetch -h`:

```
$ efetch -h | grep -m1 file
  -input         Read identifier(s) from file instead of stdin
```

So you can pass your file of IDs (e.g. `ids`) directly:

```
$ cat ids
AB610939
AB610940

$ efetch -db nuccore -input ids -format fasta
>AB610939.1 Synthetic construct RNA, spike-in microarray control RNA CRM 6204-a, clone: 6204-a-500-1
CTCGACTAGTTAATACGGTACAGGATAACCGATCGGCTTGCAACATAACGGCGTTAAGAATGCGGGAGTG
CAGTTTCCGATTCTCACATCAATCGCCAATAAGGCCTTGTCGCAATATAGACTCAACGGTTCTAGTAGCT
GATCGGTATTACGTGACGCAACCGATTAGACATGCACAATTCCTTGGTCGCTATACTACGGAAATCGTCA
GGTACTATAACCCGTCGCAGGCCTAATACGTGTCGTCACATCGCCAACCTATCGTCAGTCGGAAAGACGT
TGCTGTCTACCATCGAAACTATTTACCGCTCCGAGATTCACGAGTACGAACTCACGAGGAAGTTGCCCTA
TGTAAGGTATCACTCCAGGTACTGCGCCGATAGTACCAGGTGATCAAACGGTTGCAAGAAGGCCACGACG
TATCGGGCTCTTTAGACGTACGCTCGAGATTAAACGCGCACTGATTCACTTTAGCCCGGAATGTCTCGGT
GCGATGTAGA
>AB610940.1 Synthetic construct RNA, spike-in microarray control RNA CRM 6204-a, clone: CRM6204-a-500-2
AGACTAAATCTCGGCGTCGGTTCATACGCGCGATCGTTTGCTGTCAGGGCATACTCGAATCCGGACTCCG
ACAATTATAGGCCATCCTGAATAGCCGATCATGCGAGTCACGATAAGGCAGGCTCTGCGATATCCCGATA
TACTGGAGAAGCTGAATCCCACCTAGAGCGAACTGTCAGAGGATCGACCTCAGGCTCGCTATCATCATAA
CGGCGGACGACCTGTGTCACATTCCGAACGCTACGTGACGATATTATCTGTCGAAAGGCATAGAACGCCG
GTCAATATCCTGCGGCATTCTCTTTATCACCGGCTATAACTACTAGGTTCCGCAGATATAGACTGCGCAC
GGAACATGTAGATAGATCGAGTAGGGTAGCGATTTAACGACTCGACTTACAGACAGAGACGTAGAACGTC
AGACGAGTGGTATGCCCACCAGAGGCGATACAGGCTGTACCTGCGTAGCACTAGAGTCGTGCGTCATGCG
GACCCTATCT
```

If that were not possible, another option would be to put all your IDs as a comma separated string. If your IDs are in a file named `ids`, one per line, you can convert that to a comma-separated string like this:

```
$ tr '\n' , < ids | sed 's/,$/\n/'
AB610939,AB610940
```

That assumes GNU `sed`. If your `sed` doesn't handle `\n`, you can use this instead:

```
printf "$(tr '\n' , < ids | sed 's/,$//')" "$(cat ids)"
```

Armed with this, you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to pass the comma-separated list to `efetch`:

```
efetch -db nuccore -id $(tr '\n' , < ids | sed 's/,$/\n/') -format fasta
```

If there are limits to te number of IDs you can fetch at once, or as may well be the case, if this results in a command that is [too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642/22222), then you can use a loop as suggested in [another answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/21587/298).

---

However, be aware that while looping seems to work for `efetch`, for reasons that are not clear to me, the `esearch` developers have chosen to make it consume stdin. This means that the obvious, straightforward approach fails with `esearch`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682748/22222 for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy looping through each id in turn and each id in the single file (`idfile.txt`) is separate by a newline:

```
while read -r x; do
  efetch -db nuccore -id  "$x" -format fasta
done < idfile.txt > fetchout.fa
```

*Speculation* If the ids are not separated by a newline but a comma on a single line that might give the simultaneous efetch you're wanting. I strongly suspect that each id would need to be surround in quotation marks in such a file. Again this is just speculation and the above solution is preferred IMO.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. [That issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682748) seems to be specific to `esearch`, I cannot reproduce it with `efetch`. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @terdon world-first from the BioInfo 'nix tools police ;-)